# Avoid titles overlapping

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using the following python code to plot pie charts. However, the titles of the charts are overlapping as shown below. How am I able to make the text clearly visible without overlapping? I was thinking may be I could have a list of titles with their percentages to match the colors in the pies. Is it possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various ways.

1. set title position
   `ax.set_title(crime_type, y=1.08)`
2. displaying the labels within the pie chart

```
legend_labels = outcomes[crime_type].keys()
wedges, texts, autotexts = ax.pie(outcomes[crime_type].values(), labels=legend_labels, autopct='%1.1f%%')
ax.legend(wedges,legend_labels,title=crime_type,bbox_to_anchor=(1,0.5),loc="center left")
```

3. set size inches
   `fig.set_size_inches(w, h)`
4. set size margin
   `plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, bottom=0.1, right=0.9, top=0.9)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `connectionstyle` for annotations

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 3), subplot_kw=dict(aspect="equal"))

labels = ["A",
          "B",
          "C",
          "D",
          "E",
          "F"]

data = [225, 90, 50, 60, 100, 10]

wedges, texts = ax.pie(data)

bbox_props = dict(boxstyle="square,pad=0.3", fc="w", ec="k", lw=0.72)
kw = dict(arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-"),
          bbox=bbox_props, zorder=0, va="center")

for i, p in enumerate(wedges):
    ang = (p.theta2 - p.theta1)/2. + p.theta1
    y = np.sin(np.deg2rad(ang))
    x = np.cos(np.deg2rad(ang))
    horizontalalignment = {-1: "right", 1: "left"}[int(np.sign(x))]
    connectionstyle = "angle,angleA=0,angleB={}".format(ang)
    kw["arrowprops"].update({"connectionstyle": connectionstyle})
    ax.annotate(labels[i], xy=(x, y), xytext=(1.35*np.sign(x), 1.4*y),
                horizontalalignment=horizontalalignment, **kw)

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]